# Convergence of infinite series, defined and continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to show that the following series:

$S(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^2}{1+(kx)^2}$

is continuous for all real numbers.

I have shown that the series is defined at all real numbers by considering partial sums, but I don't know what to do in order to prove continuity. I want to show first that the series converges and I know I need that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} S(1/k) = 0$ since $S(0) = 0$.

I think I'm having the usual problem of picking which test to go with. Can we use Weierstrass M-test to show uniform convergence?

Comment: Yes, we can....

Comment: $1+(kx)^2 > k^2x^2$.

Comment: Ok....but this doesn't give us a series of constants needed for the M-test. I would this to converge uniformly for all of $\mathbb{R}$, so I can't work with only $|x|\geq1$. Can I bound $x$ somehow? Does bounding it below by the nearest integer $N$, work? I'm thinking it does. Then I am left with a $p$-series that converges.....

Comment: @Joe It does. $$\frac{x^2}{1+(kx)^2} < \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Comment: @DanielFischer  What about the case of x = 0? Why is it continuous there? Do I need to consider the limit I mentioned?

Comment: @Joe, the inequality in Daniel Fischer's comment is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok true. I think I'm just very confused because overall, I'm trying to consider the continuity on $\mathbb{C}$. I need to exclude the poles to find continuity on a domain $D$. Will the same type of proof work?

Comment: In $\mathbb{C}$, things are a little different. $0$ is an accumulation point of the poles of the summands, so it is a very problematic point. You have locally uniform convergence on the domain $\mathbb{C}\setminus \left(\{0\} \cup \left\lbrace \pm\frac{i}{k} : k \geqslant 1\right\rbrace\right)$, however.

Comment: @DanielFischer   Exactly what I've been thinking. I'm glad to know I'm on the right track. I'm still thinking using the $M$ test is the best route for proving this. Would you recommend this route?

Comment: Yes, with little changes. Since now $\lvert 1+ (kz)^2\rvert < k^2\lvert z\rvert^2$ is possible, you have to take a bound for $$\frac{\lvert z\rvert^2}{k^2\lvert z\rvert^2-1},$$ for any $z$ in the domain, for all large enough $k$, that is $< \frac{2}{k^2}$ (even uniformly on every compact subset of the domain), so you have the M-test locally, and $S$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Define
$$
S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^2}{1+k^2x^2}\\
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align}
S(x)-S_n(x)
&=\sum_{k={n+1}}^\infty\frac{x^2}{1+k^2x^2}\\
&=\sum_{k={n+1}}^\infty\frac1{1/x^2+k^2}\\
&\le\sum_{k={n+1}}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\\
&\le\frac1n
\end{align}
$$
independent of $x$. Thus, $S(x)$ is the uniform limit of the sequence of continuous $S_n(x)$, hence, continuous.